# How to use *args or **kwargs in f-strings?

Tags: python, f-string

For example, I need `*missing_vars` to be an f-string in this logging. Because for `logging.critical()` one `msg` argument is needed, so I can't do this:

```
logging.critical(f'Required environment variables are missing: {*missing_vars}')
```

I can do it without `*args`, but I need it for a beautiful output, because it turns out like this:

```
>>> logging.critical(f'Required environment variables are missing: {missing_vars}')
Required environment variables are missing: ['PRACTICUM_TOKEN', 'TELEGRAM_TOKEN']`
```

But, I want like this:

```
Required environment variables are missing: PRACTICUM_TOKEN, TELEGRAM_TOKEN
```

My function:

```
def check_tokens():
    """Checks the availability of environment variables."""
    ENV_VARS = {
        'PRACTICUM_TOKEN': PRACTICUM_TOKEN,
        'TELEGRAM_TOKEN': TELEGRAM_TOKEN,
        'TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID': TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID,
    }
    missing_vars = [var for var, value in ENV_VARS.items() if not value]
    if missing_vars:
        logging.critical(f'Required environment variables are missing: {*missing_vars}') # <--
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: `f'{", ".join(map(repr, missing_vars))}'`

Comment: `{*missing_vars}` doesn't work because a starred expression is not allowed in this context. `logging.critical` would have still got a single string argument

Comment: then how do I get the beautiful output that I gave in the example?

Comment: Using the code provided in the first context. You map each item to its representation then join each value together separated by a comma and a space

Comment: Change `repr` to `str` or use `", ".join(missing_vars)` directly if all elements of `missing_vars` are strings.

Comment: thank you! output now is `CRITICAL:root:Required environment variables are missing: PRACTICUM_TOKEN, TELEGRAM_TOKEN, TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID`
Now I'm wondering if my code can be shortened? Does it happen in practice that I declare message for `missing_vars` separately `from logging.critical()`. [check_tokens()](https://i.imgur.com/7NWDokT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments of Mechanic Pig, I have updated my function and the output I need now, thank you!

```
def check_tokens():
    """Checks the availability of environment variables."""
    ENV_VARS = {
        'PRACTICUM_TOKEN': PRACTICUM_TOKEN,
        'TELEGRAM_TOKEN': TELEGRAM_TOKEN,
        'TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID': TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID,
    }
    missing_vars = [var for var, value in ENV_VARS.items() if not value]
    if missing_vars:
        logging.critical(
            f'Required environment variables are missing: '
            f'{", ".join(missing_vars)}'
        )
    else:
        return True
```

Output:

```
CRITICAL:root:Required environment variables are missing: PRACTICUM_TOKEN, TELEGRAM_TOKEN, TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID
```